# display Fibonacci sequence with disp_function in matlab

Tags: matlab, fibonacci, disp

i want to result Fibonacci sequence from its  formula:

`1+sqrt(5)/2).^n-(1-sqrt(5)/2).^n)/sqrt(5);`

by disp function,not fprintf;but i couldn't. how can write it by disp to below form:
`f(0)= 0
f(1)= 1
f(2)= 1
f(3)= 2`

Comment: disp(f) ? Simply that I guess

Comment: Please do not change the intent of a question to such an extent that you invalidate existing answers. Instead, try to adapt the existing answer to suit your needs (this is rather easy, it's called "vectorisation"), and when you get stuck with that, ask a **new and specific** question about that.

Comment: i had a specific question ,but it was incomplete. so i edited it.

Answer (score 2):

- First of all, you had errors in you code when calculate Fibonacci sequence, where brackets should surround `1+sqrt(5)` and `1-sqrt(5)`
- Secondly, you can remove `;` at the end of expression `f = ...`, such that it will display `f` in the command window

**Example**

```
n = 1:10;
f=(((1+sqrt(5))/2).^n-((1-sqrt(5))/2).^n)/sqrt(5)
```

such that

```
f =

    1.0000    1.0000    2.0000    3.0000    5.0000    8.0000   13.0000   21.0000   34.0000
```

or display result like below

```
for n = 1:10
  f=(((1+sqrt(5))/2).^n-((1-sqrt(5))/2).^n)/sqrt(5);
  disp(['F(',num2str(n-1),')=',num2str(f)]);
end
```

such that

```
F(0)=1
F(1)=1
F(2)=2
F(3)=3
F(4)=5
F(5)=8
F(6)=13
F(7)=21
F(8)=34
F(9)=55
```

**UPDATE**

If you would like to apply `arrayfun`, you can use the code below

```
a =input('n:');
n = 1:a;
fdisp = @(n) disp(['F(',num2str(n-1),')=',num2str((((1+sqrt(5))/2).^n-((1-sqrt(5))/2).^n)/sqrt(5))]);

arrayfun(fdisp,n)
```

Comment: hi i want to display like this:F(0)= 0
F(1)= 1
F(2)= 2
F(3)= 4
F(4)= 9
F(5)= 19
F(6)= 40
F(7)= 86
F(8)= 181
F(9)= 384
F(10)= 813

Comment: @amir1122 you should take the first advice of Thomas into account. Actually you're not computing the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: can you display it without 'for loop'?

Comment: @amir1122 I don't it is possible without a `for` loop

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding could you do it with `arrayfun()` without a loop?

Comment: @SecretAgentMan see my update

Comment: no i didn't try it. can you write its script for me?

Comment: @amir1122 see my update

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Nice job!  I thought that might work.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding I know that OP do not want to use `fprintf` but you can fully vectorized this kind of thing with: `fprintf(repmat('F(%d) = %d\n',1,2),[1:2;3:4])`

Comment: @amir1122: `arrayfun` is a way of hiding the loop, but doesn't remove it (try `edit arrayfun`!). I think that the code with the `for` loop is much more legible than the `arrayfun` alternative.

Comment: @obchardon repmat was good hint:) i could write it to this form:  a=input('n:');
n=0:a;
f=(((1+sqrt(5))/2).^n-((1-sqrt(5))/2).^n)/sqrt(5);
disp([repmat('f',length(n),1) repmat('(',length(n),1) num2str(n',1) repmat(')',length(n),1) repmat('=',length(n),1) num2str(f')]);